# Animate Button Position in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, animation, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone application that has two buttons. The general layout of my app looks like the following:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid x:Name="captionGrid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent">                                
    <Border Background="#3D3D3D" Opacity="0.4" />
    <TextBlock Text="[Some Text Goes Here]" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </Grid>

  <Button x:Name="previousButton" Click="previousButton_Click">
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
          <Border Background="#3D3D3D" Opacity="0.4" />
          <TextBlock Text="Prev." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
  </Button>

  <Button x:Name="nextButton" Grid.Column="2" Click="nextButton_Click">
    <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Border Background="#3D3D3D" Opacity="0.4" />
          <TextBlock Text="Next" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

When a user clicks a button on the screen, I want to run a Storyboard. That Storyboard needs to do three things: 1) Slide the Prev button to the left so that it is out of view. 2) Slide the Next button to the right so that it is out of view. and 3) Slide the captionGrid down so that it is out of view. I can't seem to animate the positions of these three elements though. Margin is a Thickness so it is not directly supported by Silverlight. If I use a Canvas as the background element, not everything fits to the width/height of the screen.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this?  If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RenderTransform property to animate. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx , the section titled "Animating Transforms"